# SQL reflect data for all days

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a table in SQL where I reflect data for all days of a particular month.

For example, even if there is no Sale transaction for a particular day, the day for the particular employee should still be reflective in the table.

Scenario for the question. I am working with the following dates for this example: 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th Jan 2022.

The raw data is as follows:

| Name | Date | SaleAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-01-01 | 154875 |
| John | 2022-01-03 | 598752 |

As seen above, we only have data for the 1st and 3rd.

The outcome should look as follows:

| Name | Date | SaleAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-01-01 | 154875 |
| John | 2022-01-02 | NULL |
| John | 2022-01-03 | 598752 |
| John | 2022-01-04 | NULL |

As seen above, the 2nd and 4th should be included even though there was no activity for those days.

What I am currently trying:

I have a master date table which is being used as a RIGHT JOIN on the transaction table. However, the final outcome of my table is as follows:

| Name | Date | SaleAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-01-01 | 154875 |
| NULL | 2022-01-02 | NULL |
| John | 2022-01-03 | 598752 |
| NULL | 2022-01-04 | NULL |

As seen above, the 'Name' field returns as NULL. The SaleAmount however should reflect NULL to indicate no transactions happening.

I would appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: Do you want a row on January 2nd for _every single_ employee that had at least one transaction on _any other day_? Or is the set already explicitly filtered to a single employee?

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand. Yes, each employee would have a line for the 2nd Jan.

Comment: When you add an employee will you go back to the beginning of time and add rows showing they had no sales? It makes more sense to handle "no sales" as a matter of an `outer join` with a calendar table when querying the data rather than explicitly storing a lot of "nothing to see here, move along."

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to

- Start with the date table
- Cross join to your employee/salesperson table so you now have one row for each salesperson on each date
- Left join the sales orders for that date + salesperson combo to get the sum of their sales for that day.  If they have none, it'll show null:

```sql
select emp.Name
      ,dat.Date
      ,sum(ord.Amount) as SaleAmount
from            dateList    dat
     cross join salesPerson emp
      left join salesOrder  ord on ord.OrderDate = dat.Date and ord.SalesPersonId = emp.SalesPersonId
group by emp.Name
        ,dat.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list of dates on the fly. as example per month

```
Declare @year int = 2022, @month int = 7;
WITH numbers
as
(
    Select 1 as value
    UNion ALL
    Select value + 1 from numbers
    where value + 1 <= Day(EOMONTH(datefromparts(@year,@month,1)))
)
SELECT datefromparts(@year,@month,numbers.value) Datum FROM numbers
```

then left join to your table.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Recursive CTE` as the following:

```
Declare @startDate as date ='2022-01-01';
Declare @endDate as date ='2022-01-31';
With CTE As
(
    Select Distinct Name_ nm,@startDate dt From SalesDates
    Where Date_ Between @startDate And @endDate
    Union All
    Select nm, DateAdd(Day,1,dt) From CTE
    Where DateAdd(Day,1,dt)<=@endDate
)

Select C.nm as [Name],C.dt as [Date], S.SaleAmount 
From CTE C Left Join SalesDates S
On S.Date_=C.dt 
And S.Name_=C.nm 
Order By C.nm,C.dt
```

You can change the values of `@startDate` and `@endDate` according to the period you want.

See a demo from ***[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c02c92e1a330126a83b48e6f9283638)***.